# how do i put a string before and after a variable in my print statement

Tags: python

```
user = input("enter username")
print("hello" ,user "how are you?")
```

I am expecting it to say "hello", then the name of the user that gets inputted, then "how are you?", but it keeps giving me a syntax error that doesn't give any other clues as to what's wrong. I have tried making a function like so:

```
def hello(g):
    print("hello", g)


hello()
name = input("What is your name? ")
hello(name)
print("Thank you, " ,name "for logging in")
```

but I still get the same error

Comment: `print("hello" ,user "how are you?")` needs to be `print("hello" ,user, "how are you?")` to fix the syntax error. Likewise, `print("Thank you, " ,name "for logging in")` needs to be `print("Thank you, " ,name, "for logging in")`

Comment: You have a syntax error. You're missing a comma after `name`. Alternatively, check out f-strings, which let you interpolate variables directly into the string body, as follows: `print(f"Thank you, {name} for logging in")`.